# Twitter OAuth Identification

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

So I am trying to let my customers login in with Twitter, and just twitter.

Twitter says "You should never store a password for your users again", but how am I going to reauthenticate my users with twitters API?

If I resend the user to twitter after they have deleted their session, twitter asks the user again if they want to give acces to my application.

Is it at all possible to have seamless intergration with twitter accounts without ever storing local user data?

EDIT

It seems that the question is not extremely clear. What I have experienced using for example http://forum.jquery.com/. They use OpenID. I click "Login with google". I get redirected to google. Google remebers I gave acces to Zoho once and instantly sends me back to forums.jquery.com, this time with an access_token for zoho to authenticate me with. I have no persistent data with Zoho. Yet they can log me in.

What twitter with OAuth does is the following. A user comes to my site, they click "Login with twitter" and get redirected to twitter.
Twitter asks them **again** whether they want to give the application access to their data. Instead of the immediate redirect google does.

Is it possible for twitter to immediatly redirect the user to me. Is there a setting for me I am overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send users to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate instead of https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize. If the user is already signed into Twitter and has previously authenticated with your app they will be redirected without seeing an allow/deny prompt.

Comment: This answer works perfectly for Twitter. Do you have a similar solution to the same problem with Google OAuth? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct answer. 

Documentation now is more clearer, anyone interested have a look here
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter#tab1.

Answer (score 2):

What you store from Twitter are the user's TOKEN and user's SECRET. Those values are issued by Twitter (or any oauth provider) when you are in the process of oauth authentication.

You can get the idea using this library in PHP:

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Or this one in Ruby:

https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter

The process is quite straightforward once you tried with any real example. It is not difficult at all.

There are also some nice screencasts here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

Comment: I got that idea. I got it working even. But imagine this: The user logs into my site. I recieve their acces token and save it in a session to call the twitter api. The user comes back after two weeks. the session is lost. When I want to reauthenticate him I have to send him back to twitter. Where he has to give access for the 2nd time. Instead of twitter telling me that user "X" already gave acces once and that his acces token is "Y" without showing the user the Allow / Deny screen. I could save the acces token in a database with a user accuont, but that is what i want to avoid

Comment: well you cant not store the tokens or you wont be able to associate a user to an account in your database! storing the tokens is much less of a security risk than storing the password.

Comment: You have to save those values in any persistent storage, if not, your users will always need to go Twitter again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually read the API?

Read the [getting started](http://dev.twitter.com/start) page, you don't store passwords you store access tokens for the user. And if you want people to log in and register your going to have to store some data ;-)

Comment: How am I going to tell which user belongs to which acces token then?

Comment: How do you tell which username and password belongs to which account?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem exactly and solved it using setAuthorizedUrl method - for more details see here http://www.evilprofessor.co.uk/359-sign-in-with-twitter-using-zend-framework/

Comment: $consumer->setAuthorizeUrl('https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate');  === what I needed. But was also suggested by abraham. Nice post tho

Answer (score 0):

This tutorials might Helpful for you.

[Twitter API connect using oAuth](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/02/connect-twitter-api-with-oauth-using.html)

Comment: as I said multiple times. It's not the connection thats the problem. But Cristians comment is pretty much the answer. if I do not use persistent storage I can not automatically reauthenticate the user. shame twitter doesnt allow for automatic redirection

Answer (score 0):

Cristian comment is what I was looking for.

> You have to save those values in any persistent storage, if not, your users will always need to go Twitter again.

Shame that twitter doesn't recognize that the users have already allowed my app and redirects automatically